# Visual C++ ListBox manipulation; add a string

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, listbox

Language: Visual C++

I have two classes. TableColumnsItemType has two variables: visibleName, and dataName (both are string).
class ColumnsSortedType is a sorted linked list.

I want to use a function called UpdateListbox to add TableColumnsItemType item to the listBox in my Form1.h (item comes from my linkedList)

```
public: System::Void UpdateListBox() {
     //***********************************************************************
     //Purpose: To add items from ColumnsSortedType::list to Form1->ListBox1
     //Input: list
     //Pre: list is initialized and has data. 
     //List gets data before Form1 initilize call, or before System::UpdateListBox call
     //Output: None.
     //Post: listBox is filled with data from list
     //*************************************************************************
                 TableColumnsItemType item;
                 ColumnsSortedType list;

        string str = "This is a sample";

        item.SetDataName(str);
        item.SetVisibleName();
        list.InsertItem(item);
        str = "This is also a sample";
        item.SetDataName(str);
        item.SetVisibleName();
        list.InsertItem(item);
        list.InsertItem(item);       

        int length = list.LengthIs();
        int pos;
        for(pos = 0; pos < length; pos++)
        {
            list.GetNextItem(item);
            str = item.ReturnVisibleName();

            //add code to insert item into listbox
            this->listBox1.AddString(item); //**Here is my issue!**

        }

    }
```

I really don't want to add items to list in this function; but I want to get this function working before I start adding extra arguments to pass item and list around.
I'm having trouble adding an item to ListBox1. What is a member function that would allow me to do this? I know that Visual Basic would be something like listBox1.Items.Add

VS doesn't give me function choices when I add the dot-notation after listBox1, so I'm guessing that my syntax is incorrect. I'm having difficulty finding examples for C++ code manipulation of listboxes.